# English and Arabic text together doesn't always work in babel

Tags: luatex, babel, arabic

I am using babel to typeset a book with English as the main language and Arabic as the second language. I want to have the title ant the author written in both English and Arabic. However, the author looks really weird.

[image]

The English is supposed to be on the left and the Arabic is supposed to be on the right. Furthermore, why are the letters in the opposite order? Here is a minimal working example:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{english}
\babelprovide[onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures = TeX]{STIX Two Text}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer = HarfBuzz, Scale = MatchLowercase]{Kitab}

\title{Title لقب}
\author{Author مؤلف}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing `bidi=basic` to `bidi=bidi-l` *almost* works, but it breaks sectioning. (As of January 2023.)

Comment: @JavierBezos, do you know what’s going on with `\author` in bidireectional documents?

Comment: @Davislor Yes, there is a `tabular`, which enters in math mode. This MWE works fine in TeXLive 2021, so it’s a recent bug, which can be reproduced with `\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Author مؤلف \end{tabular}`. As a workaround, use a couple of boxes: `\mbox{Author} \mbox{مؤلف} `.

Comment: @JavierBezos Also with `\begin{tabular}[t]{c|}  Author  مؤلف \end{tabular}` the vrule appear on the left of the text.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that I only noticed this bug after updating from TeXLive 2021 to TeXLive 2022. The `\mbox{}` workaround works for me.

Comment: @JavierBezos Too bad `layout=tabular` doesn’t fix it. I think that’s just for column ordering.

Comment: @Davislor It’s for column ordering. It’s still working basically because making *everything* RTL is simpler than mixing RTL/LTR stuff (maths, graphics). Actually, I broke `tabular` when trying to fix `amsmath` .

Answer (score 1):

With `babel` version 3.85 Javier Bezos added a solution to this issue, just update your distribution

[image]